# How to check that Window.VisibilityChanged event fired because of "Display Orientation" changed?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm using Window.VisibilityChanged event in my app. Is it possible to check that  the Window.VisibilityChanged event fired because of "Display Orientation" changed? 
(VisibilityChangedEventArgs class has only 2 public properties: Handled, Visible)

Comment: I think you're looking at the wrong event. The event you want is probably `SizeChanged`.

Comment: I'm using VisibilityChanged because i also need to check when my app goes to background (f.e. after clicking "Windows" button on device)/

Comment: Then you need to listen to both events. VisiblityChanged tells you about visibility changes, not orientation changes.

Comment: Watch out for square displays ;).  Use the DisplayProperties.OrientationChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited 2/6/2013: this is not an answer, but observed behavior that is perhaps interesting but fragile to rely on :)**

Empirically **in the simulator**, it looks like a change in orientation fires the following sequence

```
VisibilityChanged  
OrientationChanged  
VisibilityChanged
```

so you could just set a sentinel value in [OrientationChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.display.displayproperties.orientationchanged.aspx), test it in [VisibilityChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.visibilitychanged.aspx) and then reset it there.  You'd be able to detect the second occurrence which it sounds like it's the one you want.

That same sample app though behaves differently on a device, where I observe NO VisibilityChanged events while app remains in focus and device is turned, but two additional VisibilityChanged events at the end when app is suspended, the device is rotated, and app is resumed.

Comment: Don't assume that an orientation change is always accompanied by visibility changes. Those are side effects of the rotation animation and are not contractual.

Comment: hence the "empirically" :)

Comment: Jim, i don't think that the sentinel value can helps..f.e. the user can click "Windows" button (VisibilityCnahged will fire) and after that start rotating the device (the sentinel value will be incorrect)

Comment: probably should regroup and ask *what* your are trying to accomplish. As @RaymondChen mentioned there isn't a 'contract' here, and on a device I'm seeing different behavior, including two ADDITIONAL visibility changed events firing in the context of click windows button, rotate, click windows button, but NO visibility changed while this same app is active and rotated.

Comment: I check some important application settings in the event handler of VisibilityChanged. My problems is: when the app is active and i rotate device the event handler of VisibilityChanged is fired. I cannot find a way how to check that VisibilitedChanged was fired  because of OriontationChanged. I cannot use a flag and Display.OrientationChaged event because this event is fired in active and background mode of the app.

Comment: ok, but that's an implementation, what's the functional goal?  Perhaps there's another way to get there? And as I found on device, OrientationChanged does not imply VisibiltyChanged anyway.

Comment: The functional goal is to show specific message each time you switch away, even if it’s only been 1 sec. I'm using Microsoft surface for testing and i every time when the app is active and i rotate the device the events fire in order: VisibilityChanged (e.Visible=false), OrientationChanged, VisibilityChanged( e.Visible=true)